# Collecting Closed Balls $B_\varepsilon(X)$ on a space $S$...

Tags: general-topology

I was thinking these days about open sets, closed balls, ...etc and how these concept relate to each other and I have some questions. Suppose you have an arbitrary *topological* space $S$, and you have a lot of points $X$ in it. Then you draw closed balls $B_\varepsilon(X)$ around each point, $\varepsilon$ being the radius. Now since I'm still a beginner in topology, is it interesting to consider closed balls with the maximum possible radius $\varepsilon$ such that the ball is contained in $S$? Would the set of all these balls have interesting properties? Is it already known and discussed?

What if we consider a function $f$ that maps to each ball in $S$ a single $X$, would that function be continuous? How can we even define continuity for that? Would such function have interesting properties?

($S$ is a subspace of another metric space)

Comment: That only makes sense if S is a subspace of a particular other metric space. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer but isn't every metric space a topological space?  or is it necessary to have a metric to define the notion of an open ball in a topological space?

Comment: Every metric induces a topology. ​ (Highly different metrics can induce the same topology, which is why I phrased my previous sentence that way.) ​ It is "necessary ... in a topological space", but not "to define ... of an open" _set_. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer ok, so i will add that $S$ is a subspace of another metric space

Comment: If $S$ is a metric space (or subspace of a metric space, same thing), then the ball in $S$ of center $X$ and radius $\epsilon$ is by definition the set of $y$ in $S$ whose distance from $X$ is less than $\epsilon$.  So you can make $\epsilon$ as big as you want, that ball will still be contained in $S$ by its definition.  I feel like you're maybe asking something else?

Comment: I believe the $\epsilon$ you're referring to is oftentimes called "injectivity radius".

Comment: @D_S right, i'm asking whether the collection of all the biggest possible balls for each point $X$ has some interesting properties (you take point $X$, then you look for maximum $\varepsilon$ so that $B_ \varepsilon(X)\in S$), or if it is already discussed in the literature right?

Comment: @Nephry interesting, could you please give more explanations on that? i search but i find obscure definition "The injectivity radius at a point p of a Riemannian manifold is the largest radius for which the exponential map at p is a diffeomorphism."

Comment: You mean $B_{\epsilon}(X) \subseteq S$, I think.  If we're thinking of the same thing, you always have $B_{\epsilon}(X) \subseteq S$ no matter what $X$ is or how big $\epsilon$ is.  The space $S$ is the universe.

Comment: @D_S but like for example if $S$ is if you draw a closed curve, and it has infinitely many elements in it, you know what i'm saying?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: @D_S okay, i realized that it's my error, instead of open balls, we would rather have a closed curve (example circle, or disk should i say) and at each point we map it into the maximum possible closed ball, that is greatest $\varepsilon$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)$  $\subset$ of that closed curve, is it clear now?